# AUCTeX deleting pairs

Tags: latex, auctex

I'm trying to get deletion of pairs (e.g. `()`, `[]`, `\(\)`, `\left(\right)`, etc.) to work more automatically, but I'm running into problems with each.

If I have `electric-pair-mode` enabled, I can press backspace after inserting a pair of parentheses/brackets/braces, and the entire pair is deleted. However, `electric-pair-mode` doesn't seem as robust as the built-in pair completion of AUCTeX, so I'd rather not use it if possible. My problem is that in order to delete a pair with `electric-pair-mode` disabled, I have to manually delete each item in the pair, rather than it auto-deleting the entire pair. Is it possible to just delete the first item in the pair (whether it's a single character, or something like `\left{`) and have it delete the whole pair?

Comment: You ask two questions here. Please move one of them to another post - one question per post, please.

Comment: @Drew My bad. I've fixed it.

Comment: Thank you...........